# Explicit type conversion not allowed from "int_const" to "contract"

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am trying to deploy a contract from another contract following the example from [here](https://ethereumdev.io/interact-with-other-contracts-from-solidity/)

At some point the example states:

> Instanciating a new Counter for someone will look like this:

```
   function createCounter() public {
        require (_counters[msg.sender] == Counter(0));
        _counters[msg.sender] = new Counter(msg.sender);
    }
```

> We first check if the person already owns a counter. If he does not own a counter we instantiate a new counter by passing his address to the Counter constructor and assign the newly created instance to the mapping.

However, when I try that in my factory contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Factory {
    mapping(address => Campaign) _campaigns;

    function createCampaign(uint minContrib) public {
        require(_campaigns[msg.sender] == Campaign(0));
        _campaigns[msg.sender] = new Campaign(minContrib, msg.sender);
    }
 }


...


contract Campaign {
 
    /* Irrelevant code skipped ... */

    constructor (uint minContrib, address creator) {
        manager = creator;
        minContribution = minContrib;
    }
```

compilation error pops:

> from solidity:
> TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "int_const 0" to "contract Campaign".
> --> contracts/3_Ballot.sol:10:43:
> |
> 10 |         require(_campaigns[msg.sender] == Campaign(0));
> |                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^

What comparison is being made here exactly?

`require (_counters[msg.sender] == Counter(0));`

What is `Counter(0)`? An instance of contract (like `new Counter(0)`) or a type conversion of parameter 'int_const' to 'contract'?

Answer (score 1):

Found this [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/83494) which made things a bit clearer.

Apparently this is trying to compare the Contract deployed at address 0 with thatever is stored at _counters[msg.sender] (which I believe should be the address of a deployed contract).

```
require (_counters[msg.sender] == Counter(0));
```

With that in mind, I get the error is saying "we're expecting a Counter or address of contract and you give us an int".

I fixed it with `Counter(address(0))`.